# Non-EU spouse: right to work in Italy/Live in the USA

Tags: italy, italy-aire

I am an Italian citizen and with my wife of 18 years, we have 2 children, who are Italian citizens. She is a dual US/Russian citizen. Our marriage is registered on the "AIRE". We live in US. Does she have automatic right to work in Italy? We think about semi-retiring in Italy but likely need some supplemental work income. Thank you.

Comment: She has a right to work in Italy if she moves there *with you,* because Italy (unlike some other EU countries) extends the same rights to the family members of its citizens that it must extend to the family members of other EU citizens.